I can't add a new server to the Galera MariaDB cluster. I get an error
I have a Galera cluster of three servers. It was decided to decommission the old third server and instead create a new one and include it in the cluster.
I made a copy of the database via Maria backup and transferred it to a new third server. I also tried via wsrep_sst_donor="node2" and I also tried it through innodb_force_recovery = 0.
When I try to execute systemctl start mariadb.service in the log I get the following error:
2024-05-03 14:05:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 4941559)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2024-05-03 14:05:48 2 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Group state: b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea:4941559                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2024-05-03 14:05:48 2 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 9 (4, 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2024-05-03 14:05:48 2 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea:4941559, view# 103: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 0, protocol version 3                                                                                    
2024-05-03 14:05:48 2 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.                                                                                                                                                                                           
2024-05-03 14:05:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.52.28.11' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --parent '5017' --mysqld-args --wsrep_start_position=b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea:4859750'                                         
WSREP_SST: [INFO] rsync SST started on joiner (20240503 14:05:48.954)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2024-05-03 14:05:49 2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.                                                                                                                                                                                  
2024-05-03 14:05:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 4941559, protocol version: 4                                                                                                                                                                  
2024-05-03 14:05:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2024-05-03 14:05:49 2 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea): 1 (Operation not permitted)                         
         at /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():467. IST will be unavailable.                                                                                                                                                      
2024-05-03 14:05:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (node3) requested state transfer from 'node2'. Selected 2.0 (node2)(SYNCED) as donor.                                                                                                                                         
2024-05-03 14:05:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 4941559)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2024-05-03 14:05:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 2                                                                                                                                                                                             
2024-05-03 14:05:49 2 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea:4941559                                                                                                                             
2024-05-03 14:05:50 0 [Note] WSREP: (17ce3361, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off                                                                                                                                                                    
Terminated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Cleanup after exit with status: 3 (20240503 14:07:33.893)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup: rsync PID=5153, stunnel PID=0 (20240503 14:07:33.895)                                                                                                                                                                                      
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. (20240503 14:07:34.408)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
2024-05-03 14:07:34 0 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.52.28.11' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --parent '5017' --mysqld-args --wsrep_start_position=b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea:4859750: 3 (No such process)
2024-05-03 14:07:34 0 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno and wsrep_gtid_domain_id from joiner script.                                                                                                                                                                  
2024-05-03 14:07:34 0 [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 3 (No such process)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2024-05-03 14:07:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit     

                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               

The configuration of my donor servers and the new server is as follows:
Donor node (node2)
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)                               
MariaDB-common  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-backup  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-client  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-compat  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-server  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MySQL-python    x86_64  1.2.5-1.el7                                
postfix         x86_64  2:2.10.1-9.0.1.el7.centos.plus             
redhat-lsb-core x86_64  4.1-27.el7.centos.1                        

my.cnf
[client-server]                                                    
                                                                   
#                                                                  
# include *.cnf from the config directory                          
#                                                                  
                                                                   
                                                                   
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d                                          
                                                                   
[mysqld]                                                           
                                                                   
sql_mode="ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"                                     
                                                                   
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11200M                                   
                                                                   
log_error = /var/log/mysql_error.log                               
                                                                   
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mariadb.err                               
general_log                                                        
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb.log                        
slow_query_log                                                     
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log                
long_query_time=5                                                  
                                                                   
                                                       
galera.cnf                                                         
                                                        
[mysqld]                                                           
                                                                   
binlog_format=ROW                                                  
default-storage-engine=innodb                                      
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2                                         
bind-address=0.0.0.0                                               
                                                                   
# Galera Provider Configuration                                    
wsrep_on=ON                                                        
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so                  
                                                                   
# Galera Cluster Configuration                                     
wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"                                
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.55.28.8,10.55.28.9,10.52.28.11"  
                                                                   
# Galera Synchronization Configuration                             
wsrep_sst_method=rsync                                             
                                                                   
# Galera Node Configuration                                        
wsrep_node_address="10.55.28.9"                                    
wsrep_node_name="node2"  

New node (node3)
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)                               
MariaDB-common  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-backup  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-client  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-compat  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       
MariaDB-server  x86_64  10.3.35-1.el7.centos                       

my.cnf
[client-server]                                                    
                                                                   
#                                                                  
# include *.cnf from the config directory                          
#                                                                  
                                                                   
                                                                   
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d                                          
                                                                   
[mysqld]                                                           
                                                                   
sql_mode="ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"                                     
                                                                   
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11200M                                   
                                                                   
log_error = /var/log/mysql_error.log                               
                                                                   
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mariadb.err                               
general_log                                                        
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb.log                        
slow_query_log                                                     
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log                
long_query_time=5                                                  
                                                                   
                                                       
galera.cnf                                                         
                                                        
[mysqld]                                                           
                                                                   
binlog_format=ROW                                                  
default-storage-engine=innodb                                      
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2                                         
bind-address=0.0.0.0                                               
                                                                   
# Galera Provider Configuration                                    
wsrep_on=ON                                                        
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so                  
                                                                   
# Galera Cluster Configuration                                     
wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"                                
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.55.28.8,10.55.28.9,10.52.28.11"  
                                                                   
# Galera Synchronization Configuration                             
wsrep_sst_method=rsync                                             
                                                                   
# Galera Node Configuration                                        
wsrep_node_address="10.52.28.11"                                   
wsrep_node_name="node3"  

I tried restoring via MariaDB backup. I tried to start synchronization via
wsrep_sst_donor="node2"

Tried it via
innodb_force_recovery = 0

I get the error:

WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (b71c5285-334d-11ed-a013-338ba1f6e1ea): 1 (Operation not permitted)

And I need the third server to synchronize with the Galera cluster.

I've never used galera, but it seems highly unlikely you should load a backup into a new node instead of having it start and ask for the data it needs.

@ysth I tried deleting everything from /var/lib/mysql
and running with the wsrep_sst_donor="node2" option doesn't work :(

It looks like a 90 second systemd timeout. Extend TimeoutStartSec

Hello friends!
The problem was that from node3 I had a connection to port 4444 to node1 and node2, but back from node1 and node2 to node3 and port 4444 I had no connection. Thanks everyone. The issue can be closed for now!
Have a nice day, everyone!
